# ¿Se puede eliminar un parámetro si el valor que le paso es null?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Existe alguna función en powershell que compruebe si esta vacío el valor y que deje de usar el parámetro entonces.

```
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule 
-RuleType $Rule.RuleType 
-Scope $createdScope 
-URL $Rule.URL 
-AssignmentCollection $Rule.AssignmentCollection 
-Confirm $Rule.Confirm 
-FilterBehavior $Rule.FilterBehavior 
-MatchingString $Rule.MatchingString 
-PropertyValue $Rule.PropertyValue 
-SearchApplication $Rule.SearchApplication 
-UrlScopeRuleType $Rule.UrlScopeRuleType 
-ManagedProperty $Rule.ManagedProperty
```

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
if ($variablename) { 'No es nulo' }
```